# yet and nevertheless together

Tags: word-usage, american-english

How is this sentence correct:

> Running an insurance agency left Charles Ives little time for composition, yet he nevertheless developed a unique musical idiom.

*Yet* and *nevertheless* cannot be used together; it's redundant isn't it? The sentence comes out of the SAT book of Barron's. So it should be correct, but I don't know how. Please explain.

Thanks.

Comment: `Running an insurance agency left Charles Ives little time for composition, yet (=but) he nevertheless (despite all that was mentioned) developed a unique musical idiom.` I don't think two words are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @JayHook: I don't think there's anything wrong with using both words together, ***but even so*** I don't think it would make any difference if you transposed your two bracketed "definitions". The repetition is simply an acceptable stylistic device (that may arguably add emphasis). It's spurious to postulate that each element actually means something different (just as I could use either or both of ***but*** and ***even so*** in my first sentence; they're effectively equivalent).

Comment: From Google Books: [***yet nevertheless***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22yet+nevertheless%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - 188,000 results. And for the equally "tautological" [***but nevertheless***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but+nevertheless%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - 3,250,000 results. Only a misguided pedant could seriously maintain there's anything "wrong" with such common usages.

Comment: I think JayHook explained this very well, yet nevertheless I think FumbleFingers' comment has merit as well.

Comment: thank you everybody. can you please tell me if it is also fine to use "but, however", "yet, however", "but/yet in spite of" in this or a similar sentence instead of "yet" and "nevertheless" respectively?

Comment: cux I didn't find these other combinations anywhere on the net or in any of the pieces I have ever read..but are any of these structures that I have mentioned in my comment above also correct?

Comment: ladybel: I'm having trouble thinking of a good example of "but, however", yet in spite of that, I think your third one might be possible. **The key is that the two phrases must complement each other somehow** – either for emphasis (as FumbleFingers did, with _but even so_), or as JayHook explained, where one of the pair functions as a pure conjunction, while the other focuses the scope of the sentence somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they are redundant and the (very common) structure does add a bit of meaning in this case.  Here's my analysis:

**Yet** emphasizes *surprise or irony* in compare/contrast. **Nevertheless** is an adverb meaning *"in spite of that"* and applies to the relationship between "little time" and "develop".  Here is the original and my "interpreted" sentence to show how I understand the distinctions (roughly):

- ORIGINAL: Running an insurance agency left Charles Ives little time for composition, **yet** he **nevertheless** developed a unique musical idiom.
- INTERPRETED: Running an insurance agency left Charles Ives little time for composition, **but surprisingly** he developed **(in spite of "little time")** a unique musical idiom.

Sorry it's a little awkward to use a parenthetical expression, but its the best way I could explain this concisely.  Compare with a sentence in which **nevertheless** would not work out so well:

- "The visitors complained loudly about the heat, **yet** they continued to play golf every day."  (From [Guide to Grammar and Writing](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm#yet).)
- "The visitors complained loudly about the heat, **yet** they **nevertheless** continued to play golf every day."

In the second sentence, I think **nevertheless** is too wordy.  It's also vague: is **nevertheless** compared to their complaining, or to the heat, or to both?